# math.gamma limited by float 64 bit range - any way to assign more bits?

Tags: python

I am trying to get results of the gamma function for big numbers.
I am limited, it seems, by the 64 bit float.
See this print out from my python console:

```
math.gamma(171)
7.257415615307998e+306
math.gamma(172)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: math range error
```

How can I get more range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/)

```
import mpmath
print(mpmath.gamma(1000)) # 4.02387260077094e+2564
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have permissions to reach inside the `math` package to alter its data types.  You would have to write your own `gamma` implementation, using your choice of "BIGNUM" (generic term, not a specific data type) underlying type.  If you restrict your arguments, you could already do this with Python's automatic integer extensions.

Comment: while this doesn't exactly solve my problem, it does answer the question I asked and I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working with `math.gamma`, you could instead work with `math.lgamma`, the logarithm of the gamma function, which has a larger range.

```py
import math

print(math.lgamma(171))  # 706.5730622457874
print(math.lgamma(172))  # 711.71472580229
```

If you're using something like `decimal.Decimal`, which supports a larger range than a `float`, you can use this result to reproduce the desired gamma function.

```py
import math
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal(math.lgamma(1000)).exp())  # 4.023872600769312967956830726E+2564
```